# change log between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in the SQLserver with the same schema. these tables are at timestamp t and t+1.i want to insert changes that happen in table 1 and table 2.
for example:

`#table 1` at time t

```
id |a |b
---|--|-
1  |1 |1
2  |2 |2
3  |3 |3
```

and `#table 2` at time t+1

```
id |a |b
---|--|-
1  |1 |2
2  |2 |2
3  |4 |3
```

result

```
id|col_name|old_val|new_val
--|--------|-------|--------
1 |b       |1      | 2
3 |a       |3      | 4
```

Comment: So what have you tried and why didn't it work? What are you asking here ("I want" isn't a question, that's *requesting* us to provide you a solution). Can `#Table 1` or `#Table 2` have other columns other than `a` or `b`? I suggest looking at univoting (either using `UNPIVOT` or the `VALUES` table constructor) and the `JOIN` operator.

Comment: Meet [sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18) They have a nice little tool called Text To DML - where you paste in your tabular data and they generate the DML statements for it. Then, [edit] your question with [proper](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info) sample data, and don't forget to include your current attampts to solve the problem.

Comment: @BenyaminKarimi . . . I don't know why the question is being downvoted.  It is one of the more interesting questions today.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select v.*
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id cross apply
     (values ('a', t1.a, t2.a), ('b', t1.b, t2.b)
     ) v(colname, old_val, new_val)
where old_val <> new_val;
```

This is joining the tables together and the unpivoting them by column.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=18fce33e3ce43b363a7536662cefd067) is a db<>fiddle.